# Why ng-model in directive template not updating when value is changed from the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I'm Using a directive and from two way binding i'm changing a date object variable that is passed to the directive initially.

But when I do some changes to the date variable like

```
$scope.valueee = 1;
$scope.press = function(){
    $scope.searchterm.setHours($scope.valueee++, 0, 0, 0);
  if(!$scope.$$phase)$scope.$apply()
}
```

but it wont update the view with the ng-model in the template view inside the directive

```
'ng-model="term"'
```

Following is the code example

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/JC28H/30/)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are running into this issue when binding directly to a primitive:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Emphasis mine

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try **2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope**. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New AngularJS developers often do not realize that ng-repeat, ng-switch, ng-view, ng-include and ng-if all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. (See [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5xALZf1IXOloqcbvBD1v?p=preview) for a quick illustration of the problem.)
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with ng-switch.

The [plunker linked to above above](http://plnkr.co/edit/5xALZf1IXOloqcbvBD1v?p=preview) shows your issue directly (source below):

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  /*
  ng-repeat generates new scopes which will be child scopes of the scope within
  which they are generated. In other words, this scope is the parent scope for
  the child scopes generated by the ng-repeat in this example. Child scopes
  inherit things from their parent's scope.
  */

  // The initial main image 
  var initialImg = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-z8kzafZYkfQ/UERf6IbjJJI/AAAAAAAAALE/qaAxqqawXpM/s1600/Cat+Pictures+1.jpg";
  
  /*
  A primitive holding the URL for the main image
  
  This scope's child scopes will "shadow" this primitive, which basically means
  they'll get their own copy that is initialy the same value. The child scopes
  can only see their own copy though, so modifying the value in the child scope
  does not affect the value in the parent scope.
  */
  $scope.mainImgUrl = initialImg;
  
  /*
  An object holding the URL for the main image
  
  This scope's child scopes will NOT get their own copy of this object.
  Referencing main or main.imgUrl in the child scope will reference this object
  on this scope (unless the child scope explicitly define its own "mainImg" object.)
  */
  $scope.mainImg = { url: initialImg };
  
  // Our 'thumbnail' images
  $scope.images = [
      "http://happy.fm/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/random-owl.jpg",
      "http://www.superhumor.com/emoticonos/8761.gif"
  ];
  
});
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
    <h1>ng-click inside ng-repeat setting value on parent scope</h1>
    
    <p>
    Example to illustrate the nuances of prototypical inheritance. See 
    <a href="http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_10#comment-977962885">this Angular Tutorial Step 10 question</a>
    and
    <a href="https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes">Understanding Scopes</a>
    .
    </p>
    
    
    <h3>Using primitive:</h3>
      
    <div class="example">
    
      <img class="mainImg" ng-src="{{mainImgUrl}}" />
      
      <p>This is the parent scope with the main image.</p>
      
      <p>$scope.mainImgUrl == {{mainImgUrl}}</p>
  
      <div class="thumbs">
      
        <p>Thumbs generated with ng-repeat, with ng-click setting <strong>$scope.mainImgUrl</strong> (click on them to see what happens):</p>
        
        <div class="thumbDiv" ng-repeat="img in images">
        
          <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="mainImgUrl = img" />

          <p>This is a child scope generated by ng-repeat.</p>
          
          <p>$scope.mainImgUrl == {{mainImgUrl}}</p>
          
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
    
    <h3>Using object:</h3>
    
    <div class="example">
      
      <img class="mainImg" ng-src="{{mainImg.url}}" />
      
      <p>This is the parent scope with the main image.</p>
      
      <p>$scope.mainImg.url == {{mainImg.url}}</p>
  
      <div class="thumbs">
      
        <p>Thumbs generated with ng-repeat, with ng-click setting <strong>$scope.mainImg.url</strong> (click on them to see what happens):</p>
        
        <div class="thumbDiv" ng-repeat="img in images">
        
          <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{img}}" ng-click="mainImg.url = img" />
          
          <p>This is a child scope generated by ng-repeat.</p>
          
          <p>$scope.mainImg.url == {{mainImg.url}}</p>
          
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi I have changed the way you described but still the same problem exists ( updated jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JC28H/31/ )